# ABC, NBC vs. the BBC and the ABC

Tags: articles

I am writing a style guide at my company, and for the life of me, I can't explain why U.S. broadcasters "ABC" and "NBC" seem to need no article as a noun, while the U.K. broadcaster "BBC" always gets one. And when I think about the Australian network "ABC," my instinct tells me that an article is needed.

One difference is that the BBC is a corporation, while ABC (U.S.) and NBC are companies, but that's not part of the thought process. And by themselves, "American" and "British" are opposites again: "He is an American, but she is British." Simply considering the first word in NBC — National — would confuse the issue even more.

Of course "British" and "Australian" are more specific in location than "National" and "American" — three Americas as in north, central. and south — but I naturally associate "American" as being the U.S.

Can someone please tell me what I am missing?

Answer (score 12):

The Chicago Manual of Style recommends:

> Generally, if “the” is part of the name, but not absorbed by the
>   abbreviation, use “the” as if the abbreviation were spelled out:
>
> - The NFL comprises thirty-one teams.
> - NFL games rarely get postponed owing to inclement weather.
> - In its ninety-two years, the NAACP has been a cornerstone of American    civil liberties organizations.
> - NAACP membership is open to all who can afford it.
>
> In other words, use “the” unless the abbreviation is used as an
>   adjective or unless the abbreviation spelled out wouldn’t take a
>   definite article (e.g., American Telephone and Telegraph).

In your examples:

- “The” is part of “the British Broadcasting Corporation” and is *not*
  absorbed by the abbrevation, so it’s “the BBC.”
- American Broadcasting Company is officially ABC, Inc., so it’s “ABC.”
- NBC is officially [NBCUniversal](http://www.nbcuni.com/corporate); no “the.”
- The Austrialian Broadcasting Corporation is [commonly referred to](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Australian_Broadcasting_Corporation)
  as “the ABC.”

It’s instructive to see how the Bureau of Land Management’s [own documentation](http://www.blm.gov/wo/st/en.html) (where they are “the BLM”) demonstrates CMoS’s recommended usage.

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping for something that could encompass any initialism, but that's my fault for asking such a narrow question with only widely known examples. My work is awash in acronyms and initialisms, and English is not my coworkers' first language. I need to give them concise rules to follow.

Answer (score 4):

I think it is because it has always been known as "the" British Broadcasting Corporation.  You would hear a Brit say "the BBC was showing the FA Cup Final" or "ITV was showing the FA Cup Final" but you'd never hear "BBC was showing..." or "the ITV was showing...".